# std::cin input with random number of arguments

Tags: c++, input, std

My program has to get from the user an unknown number of words, in a **single line** as an input, then be able to count them and parse their content singularly.
The maximum word number is 3 words.

I tried doing something like this

```
string arg1,arg2,arg3;

cout<< "insert your words: "<<endl;
std::cin >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3;

if (arg2.empty()){
cout<< "you inserted one word"<<endl;
   if(arg1 == "WORD"){
         cout<< "first word is WORD"<<endl;
   } else {
         cout << "first word is not WORD "<<endl;
     }

}
if (arg3.empty()){
cout<< "you inserted two words"<<endl;
}

else{
cout<< "you inserted 3 words"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

The reason I tried this is I expected `std::cin`'s **>> operator** to set the not-filled strings with null. Instead, it will wait until I put 3 not-null strings.
But at the same time, I would like to keep an arg-like input method, especially avoiding a *"insert first variable... insert second variable... etc* loop.

Is there a way to get a variable number of parameters using `std::cin`?

Comment: `std::cin << arg1 << arg2 << arg3;` should be `std::cin >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3;` right?  But that forces the user to enter three things.

Comment: Generalizing: Just about every time you find yourself with sequentially named or numbered variables your job will be a lot easier with an array or a [Library Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) container. If you know the number of variables ahead of time, trend toward an array or `std::array`. If you don't know ahead of time, trend toward `std::vector`.

Comment: In a single line suggests using `std::getline` to read the line into a `std::string`. Construct a `std::istringstream` around the `std::string` and read the words out of the `std::istringstream` with `>>` as per Thomas's answer below.

Comment: Because you don't know the number of inputs, you are doomed to a loop or recursion until the exit condition, no more data on the line, is found. Prefer the loop to recursion for this job because there will almost certainly be lower overhead and no chance of stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this standard pattern:

```
std::vector<string> database;
string value;
while (std::cin >> value)
{
    database.push_back(value);
}
```

The User will need to enter an EOF signal to the input to stop the loop.

You can then do something like this:

```
std::cout << "You entered " << database.size() << "words.\n";
```

This may not be able to input an *unlimited* quantity of words.  All computers have a finite amount of memory.  Tasks and programs may have less memory, depends on how much memory is allocated to your program.

**Edit 1: Per updated question**
Here's the method as a **single line**:
`while (std::cin >> value) database.push_back(value);`

I really don't understand the benefit in using a **single line** to input.

You can't put a varying amount of arguments on a **single line** during runtime.  All arguments must be present before compilation.

You *could* put the maximum amount of arguments, on a **single line**, if you know that ahead of time.

The purpose of *containers* and *loops* is so that you can handle the cases where the number of parameters is unknown at runtime, and you need to perform the same processing on more than one variable.

Comment: Question has been updated, somewhat obsoleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, input from user via `std::cin` is not that easy as expected.

If you use the `iostream` extratcor operator, you will do formated input. So, your statement `std::cin >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3;` will try to read 3 strings from the user, separated be white space (which will be ignored) and then convert the user input to the specified variables. You need to press 'enter' after typing in the last string.

That gives sometimes surprising results.

You need to know additionally, the an extraction operation `>>` will return a reference to the `stream` that it was called with. So
`std::cin >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3;` is actually `((std::cin >> arg1) >> arg2) >> arg3;`

After the first `std::cin >> arg1`, `std::cin` will be returned and the statement would look like `(std::cin >> arg2) >> arg3;`. `std::cin >> arg2` will again return `std::cin` and the next statement would be `std::cin >> arg3;`. And guess what. This will also return `std::cin`

Next you need to know that the `std::stream` `bool` operator isoverwritten. Please see a good explanation in the CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). Also the `!` operator is overloaded in a similar way.

Why is that important? You need to understand that input will stop, if one of those fail bits are set. And here we are talking especially about the `eof`, so the end-of-file bit.

So, if you want to read data, then you usually do that in a loop, until eof is hit and nor more data is available.

Example:

```
std::ifstream ifs{"c:\\temp\\test.txt"};
if (ifs) {  // bool operator will be called and check, if file-open worked
    std::string str{};
    while (ifs >> str) {   // will read all strings from the stream, until eof
    . . .
```

The problem with `std::cin` is that there is basically no eof. The terminal can provide endless data.

Cou can simulate eof, by pressing CTRL-d on uix machines and CTRL-Z in windows terminals.

Then you could also write

```
    std::string str{};
    while (std::cin >> str) {   // will read all strings from the stream, until eof (e.g. CTRL-Z)
    . . .
```

But this is a little bit clumsy, and hence the standard procedure is to read a complete line from the user via `std::getline(std::cin, str);` , then, put the string into an `std::istringstream` and then extract from the `std::istringstream`. Because, this guy will give and eof, after all data has been extracted.

And if you have the data, usually stored in a `std::vector`, you can evaluate them.

Here some example code that could help to understand the topic better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string str1{};

    // Reada complete line
    std::getline(std::cin, str1);

    // Put the whole line into a istringstream
    std::istringstream iss{ str1 };

    // Here we will store all strings from the input line
    std::vector<std::string> input{};

    std::string str2{};
    while (iss >> str2) {
        input.push_back(str2);
    }

    std::cout << "\nYou entered " << input.size() << " strings andthey are:\n\n";
    for (const std::string& str3 : input)
        std::cout << str3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And more advanced C++ code would look this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

const std::regex re{ R"(\s)" };

int main() {

    // Read a line from the user and check, if that worked
    if (std::string line{}; std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

        // Get all strings from thsi input line
        std::vector data(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {});

        // Show result to user:
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```